# Как исправить утечку памяти в CollectionView на Windows?

Tags: c#, maui

Я заметил, что если быстро крутить CollectionView вверх вниз, то будет происходить утечка памяти. Особо заметно это тогда, когда в ItemTemplate у вас находится Image. Это доходит до того, что приложение просто закрывается из-за переполнения памяти.
На GitHub почему-то все подобные проблемы помечены как закрытые, но при этом проблема не исправлена.
Так же, если выполнить навигацию на страницу, в которой будет CollectionView подобного типа, то, при выходе из этой страницы, ресурсы CollectionView никогда не освободятся.
Вроде такая проблема только на Windows, на Android у меня такого не было, да и на iOS тоже.
Так есть ли вообще какой-нибудь способ это исправить?

Comment: А почему вы думаете, что это утечка памяти? Это ваша логика, вашего приложения, вы так конкретно ее написали. Хотите иначе, настраивайте виртуализацию, чтоб видимые +- N объекты были в памяти, а остальные выгружались, также позаботьтесь о картинках, чтоб те кэшировались и выводились например только миниатюры.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ так я и так сделал кэширование изображений, а проблема всё равно остаётся. Остаётся только настроить виртуализацию, про которую вы говорите, только вот я понятия не имею, как это сделать.

Comment: В WPF это делается [так](https://metanit.com/sharp/wpf/14.5.php), то есть должна быть панель, которая поддерживает виртуализацию, тогда ей можно будет задать диапазон того, как много она будет загружать в память (скажем, 5 видимых и по 5 за диапазоном видимости), если объект вышел из этой области, то он выгружается автоматически. В MAUI я так с ходу не нашел как настраивается виртуализация, нашел в документации лишь то, что `CollectionView` по умолчанию настроена на виртуализацию. Также нашел [это](https://github.com/Redth/Maui.VirtualListView), можете по его аналогии сделать себе нужное.

Comment: Также кстати наткнулся на [это](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/11272), то есть с виртуализацией `CollectionView` был баг и она действительно не работала. Этот баг пофиксили в превью 5.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я решил проверить это на preview версии .NET 8 для MAUI и там утечки памяти нету. Но её нету из-за того, что там просто взяли, да отключили виртуализацию для CollectionView на Windows. Её вообще нет!
Это очень странное решение проблемы с их стороны. Ну а для .NET 7 версии MAUI я написал такой обходной путь:

```
public partial class App : Application
{
    public App()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Current.UserAppTheme = AppTheme.Light;
        MainPage = new AppShell();
        #if WINDOWS
        Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Handlers.Items.CollectionViewHandler.Mapper.AppendToMapping(
            "NoVirtualization", (_, collectionView) =>
        {
            Dispatcher.Dispatch(() =>
            {
                ScrollView scrollView = new()
                {
                    Orientation = (ScrollOrientation)(collectionView.ItemsLayout as ItemsLayout).Orientation
                };
                if (collectionView.Parent is IContentView view) (view as dynamic).Content = scrollView;
                else if (collectionView.Parent is Layout layout) layout[layout.IndexOf(collectionView)] = scrollView;
                scrollView.Content = collectionView;
            });
        });
        #endif
    }
}
```

Я обнаружил, что если запихнуть CollectionView внутрь ScrollView, то CollectionView будет занимать максимальный размер, который он может, соответственно ему не надо будет выгружать что-то или заново загружать, ведь свойство Height будет автоматически масштабироваться под размер всех элементов в CollectionView, из-за чего ему придётся отрисовывать все элементы, даже те, которые мы не видим. Другими словами, оно просто предотвращает фиговую виртуализацию у CollectionView под Windows, из-за чего утечка памяти не происходит.